# Saving data from spawned process into variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, child-process, spawn

I am having issues saving the results from a spawned python process. After converting data into json, I push the data to an array defined within the function before the spawn process is called, but the array keeps returning undefined. I can console.log and show the data correctly, but the array that is returned from the function is undefined. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
function sonar_projects(){
    const projects = [];
    let obj;
    let str = '';
    const projects_py = spawn('python', ['sonar.py', 'projects']);
    let test = projects_py.stdout.on('data', function(data){
        let projects = [];
        let json = Buffer.from(data).toString()
        str += json
        let json2 = json.replace(/'/g, '"')
        obj = JSON.parse(json2)
        console.log(json2)
        for(var dat in obj){
            var project = new all_sonar_projects(obj[dat].key, obj[dat].name, obj[dat].qualifier, obj[dat].visibility, obj[dat].lastAnalysisDate);
            projects.push(project); 
        }   
        for (var i= 0; i < projects.length; i++){
             console.log(projects[i].key + ' ' + projects[i].name + '  ' + projects[i].qualifier + '  ' + projects[i].visibility + '  ' + projects[i].lastAnalysisDate)
        }
        console.log(projects)
        return projects;
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, going through the NodeJS documentation, we have

1. [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)
2. [child_process.spawn(command[, args][, options])](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)
3. [Child Process Class](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess)
4. [Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html)
5. [Stream Readable Event "data"](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data)

Even though `projects_py.stdout.on(event_name, callback)` accepts an callback, it returns either the `EventEmitter`-like object, where the events are registered (in this case, `stdout` that had it's method `on` called), or the `parent` element (the `ChildProcess` named `projects_py`).

It's because the `callback` function will be called every time the `"data"` event occurs. So, if the assign of the event returned the same as the `callback` function, it'd return only one single time, and then every next happening of the `"data"` event would be processed by the function, but not would be done.

In this kind of situation, we need a way to collect and compile the data of the `projects_py.stdout.on("data", callback)` event after it's done.
You already have the collecting part. Now see the other:

Right before you create the on `"data"` event, we create a promise to encapsulate the process:

```js
    // A promise says "we promise" to have something in the future,
    //  but it can end not happening
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // First of all, we collect only the string data
        //  as things can come in parts
        projects_py.stdout.on('data', function(data){
            let json = Buffer.from(data).toString()
            str += json
        });
        
        // When the stream data is all read,
        //  we say we get what "we promised", and give it to "be resolved"
        projects_py.stdout.on("end", () => resolve(str));
        
        // When something bad occurs,
        //  we say what went wrong
        projects_py.stdout.on("error", e => reject(e));
        
    // With every data collected,
    //  we parse it (it's most your code now)
    }).then(str => {
        let json2 = str.replace(/'/g, '"')
        // I changed obj to arr 'cause it seems to be an array
        let arr = JSON.parse(json2)
        //console.log(json2)
        
        const projects = []
        // With for-of, it's easier to get elements of
        //  an object / an array / any iterable
        for(var dat of arr){
            var project = new all_sonar_projects(
                dat.key, dat.name, dat.qualifier,
                dat.visibility, dat.lastAnalysisDate
            );
            projects.push(project); 
        }
        
        // Template strings `a${variable or expression}-/b`
        //  are easier to compile things into a big string, yet still fast
        for(var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++)
            console.log(
                `${projects[i].key} ${projects[i].name} ` +
                `${projects[i].qualifier}  ${projects[i].visibility} ` +
                projects[i].lastAnalysisDate
            )
        console.log(projects)
        
        // Your projects array, now full of data
        return projects;
    // Finally, we catch any error that might have happened,
    //  and show it on the console
    }).catch(e => console.error(e));
}
```

Now, if you want to do anything with your array of projects, there are two main options:

### Promise (then / catch) way

```js
// Your function
function sonar_projects(){
    // The new promise
    var promise = ...
    
    // As the working to get the projects array
    //  is already all set up, you just use it, but in an inner scope
    promise.then(projects => {
        ...
    });
}
```

Also, you can just return the `promise` variable and do the promise-things with it out of `sonar_projects` (with then / catch and callbacks).

### *async* / *await* way

```js
// First of all, you need to convert your function into an async one:
async function sonar_projects(){
    // As before, we get the promise
    var promise = ...
    
    // We tell the function to 'wait' for it's data
    var projects = await promise;
    
    // Do whatever you would do with the projects array
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been plaguing me all morning! I am new to javascript, so thank you for the information!

Comment: @CS146R Actually, I started writing this 4 min after you posted the question, but it took me almost an hour to write it.
And I'm glad my first answer on Stack Overflow was somewhat useful.