# How to return res from an API in the same order as how the calling function is looped?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that is updated based on the user's input.

`someArray = [a, b, c]`

I want to fetch an API as I loop through the array

```
const arrayIWant = []
for ( var i=0; i<someArray.length; i++) {
    const arrayToString = []
    arrayToString.push(encodeURIComponent(someArray[i]))
    axios.get(`http://someURL&element=${arrayToString})
    .then(res => {
    arrayIWant.push(res.element)
})
}
```

It should return

```
arrayIwant = [d, e, f]
```

where

```
d, e, f returned from a, b, c respectively.
```

However, what I found is the order of d, e, f elements from the fetch request are completely random each time I invoke the fetch request through a button. What did I do wrong? Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Json fetch returning elements in random order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65694351/json-fetch-returning-elements-in-random-order)

Comment: You can use `Promise.all`

Comment: The solution Amr provided below works, which uses Promise.all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all()` to wait for all of your promises to resolve and return an array that is ordered as you want.

```js
async function someFunc() {
  const callPromises = someArray.map((element) => {
    const arrayToString = [encodeURIComponent(element)];
    return axios.get(`http://someURL&element=${arrayToString}`);
  });

  return (await Promise.all(callPromises)).map((res) => res.element);
}

const arrayIWant = someFunc();
```

If you don't want to use `async/await` you can do something like the following

```js
var arrayIWant = [];

const callPromises = someArray.map((element) => {
  const arrayToString = [encodeURIComponent(element)];
  return axios.get(`http://someURL&element=${arrayToString}`);
});

Promise.all(callPromises).then((responses) => {
  arrayIWant = responses.map((res) => res.element);
});
```

Comment: Hi Amr, thanks a lot! I can confirm your solution works. Glad I spent 3 hours last night banging my head against the wall. I clearly should not skip the documents.....